# How to change content with next and previous button at same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a scenario at where some portion of full contents can be seen. To see the other portion, user have to click the `next` button. They'll also can go back by `back` button. It might be little bit easy if next and previous links are stayed at all the partial content so that each content's link can be kept at the next and previous links. But, unfortunately, I have to keep next and previous button outside of each contents. Anyway, I can make the next button working so far. But, I can't make back button working. Also, I'm realizing that, it's not the correct way. Because, I've made the button working based on the how many time clicking on the button. `If clicked once, show the content-1, if clicked for second time, show the content-2 and so on`. But, when previous button will work, then making relation with content and click counting may not work properly. So, what's the best way to handle this scenario by jQuery?

[So far, my work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/maysmhbr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-holder">
    <div class="content" id="content-1" data-id='1' style="display: block;">
        <p>First Options</p>
        <input type="checkbox" />Item <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="content-2" data-id='2'>
        <p>Second Options</p>
        <input type="checkbox" />Item <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="content-3" data-id='3'>
        <p>Third Options</p>
        <input type="checkbox" />Item <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="back">Back</button>
    <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="end" data-id='4'>
    <p>Congratulation! You are done!</p>
    <button type="button" class="edit-previous">Edit Previous Options</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('body').on('click', '.next', function() { 
    var id = $('.content:visible').data('id');
    var nextId = $('.content:visible').data('id')+1;
    $('[data-id="'+id+'"]').hide();
    $('[data-id="'+nextId+'"]').show();

    if($('.back:hidden').length == 1){
        $('.back').show();
    }

    if(nextId == 4){
        $('.content-holder').hide();
        $('.end').show();
    }
});

$('body').on('click', '.back', function() { 
    var id = $('.content:visible').data('id');
    var prevId = $('.content:visible').data('id')-1;
    $('[data-id="'+id+'"]').hide();
    $('[data-id="'+prevId+'"]').show();

    if(prevId == 1){
        $('.back').hide();
    }    
});

$('body').on('click', '.edit-previous', function() { 
    $('.end').hide();
    $('.content-holder').show();
    $('#content-3').show();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maysmhbr/5/)**

Comment: Both have their pros and cons I find mine more stable because you don't have to mix numbers and text up so many times but in the answer of Prog you don't have to add data-id to it. Both work fine but in my opinion mine seems more stable. You should choose the one you understand best because you might need to look back in your code after months and not understand it anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

**Try This -** **[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/maysmhbr/2/)**

```
var counter = 1;
$('body').on('click', '.next', function() { 
    $('.content').hide();

    counter++;
    $('#content-'+counter+'').show();

    if(counter > 1) {
        $('.back').show();
    };
    if(counter > 3) {
        $('.content-holder').hide();
        $('.end').show();
    };

});

$('body').on('click', '.back', function() { 
    //alert(counter);
    counter--;
    $('.content').hide();
    var id = counter;    
    $('#content-'+id).show();
    if(counter<2){
            $('.back').hide();
    }


});

$('body').on('click', '.edit-previous', function() {  // UPDATED CODE
    $('.end').hide();
    $('.content-holder').show();
    $('#content-3').show();
    counter--;  // issue resolved of click twice
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle Demo - Click](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/maysmhbr/2/)**

**See the Updated Answer [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/maysmhbr/4/)**

Comment: This is good. But, problem is when click "Edit Previous Options", then Third Options ('#content-3') will be showed. From that screen, back button is working if clicked the button twice. http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/maysmhbr/3/

Comment: @user1896653 - See the Updated Answer here - http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/maysmhbr/4/

Comment: I can see the same result at your updated answer too. everything is working fine. But, when get back from "congratulation" screen, back button is not working for clicked once from "Content-3" screen. I has to click twice to make it working

Comment: I thinks It's very simple bro....you have to just put counter--; at the end on click event .!!

Comment: if it is useful for you then `upvote` and `accept` the answer will helps lot to other for correct solution :)

Comment: give me some time please. You gave me solution at first. But, I'm just thinking which process is much perfect as I mentioned at my post too what's the perfect way to handle it. There are two answers in my post already and after considering one as 'perfect way', I'll accept one! But, if it's possible, I'll accept both two answers :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not have all different "contents" in a list and just let JS to take care of everything else. That way, adding and removing content is very simple and only involves editing HTML and not JS code. [Here's a Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/maysmhbr/18/)

---

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="content">
    <li>
        <p>First Options</p>
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>Second Options</p>
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>Third Options</p>
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Item
    </li>

    <li>
        <p>Congratulation! You are done!</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**JS:**

```
var content = $('#content');
content.css('list-style-type', 'none');
content.wrap('<div id="wrapper"></div>');

var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
wrapper.append('<button id="previous">Previous</button><button id="next">Next</button>');

$('#previous').hide();

var liElements = content.children();
liElements.hide();
liElements.first().show();

var liElementCount = liElements.length;

if (liElementCount > 0) {
    var counter = 0;

    function swapContent() {
        if (counter == 0) {
            $('#previous').hide();
        } else {
            $('#previous').show();
        }

        if (counter == liElementCount - 1) {
            $('#next').hide();
        } else {
            $('#next').show();
        }

        liElements.hide();
        $(liElements.get(counter)).show();
    }

    $('#next').click(function () {
        counter++;
        swapContent();
    });

    $('#previous').click(function () {
        counter--;
        swapContent();
    });
}
```